# Difference between struct tcphdr and struct tcp

Tags: c, networking, tcp

I've found that there are two different structures for getting TCP headers namely tcp and tcphdr.
The links for both the structures are [here:tcp](http://minirighi.sourceforge.net/html/structtcp.html) and [here:tcphdr](http://www.cse.scu.edu/~dclark/am_256_graph_theory/linux_2_6_stack/structtcphdr.html) respectively.

What is the difference between them and do they depend on the system they're running?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol Readup on the tcp protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One is from http://minirighi.sourceforge.net/ Minirighi multi-threading operating system for IA-32

And another is from Linux kernel version 2.6.  ([http://www.cse.scu.edu/~dclark/am_256_graph_theory/linux_2_6_stack/structtcphdr.html](http://www.cse.scu.edu/%7Edclark/am_256_graph_theory/linux_2_6_stack/structtcphdr.html))

TCP packet/header implementation is internal to the TCP/IP stack which is usually part of OS kernel. So, there are different TCP/IP stacks and they may define different structures. What is important - to implement TCP standard according to RFC documents like https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793 which includes byte format of tcp packet headers (when sent in network).